# Magnetization and its relationship to the $\vec{H}$-field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

I am particularly confused about the relationship between $\vec{M}$ and $\vec{H}$.

I know the simple matter relationship: $\vec{M}$  = $\chi_m \vec{H}$

Furthermore, we know that (referencing Electrodynamics by Zangwill Eq. 13.47) that a sphere with any aribturary magnetization, $\vec{M}$ will produce a "demagetization" field within the sphere in the form of : $\vec{H}_M = -\frac{1}{3}\vec{M} $.

Now the question I am most confused about is: What if we know an background H-field, $\vec{H}_0$, how can we correctly find the Magnetization induced on a simple matter sphere?

From the way I see it, theres two common ways people approch this problem. First approch is to use the relation $\vec{M}$  = $\chi_m \vec{H}_0$, but I don't see how this makes sense? That is because, I believe that the background field will induce a "demagnitzation" field inside the sphere thus making the total H-field inside the sphere $\vec{H} = \vec{H_0} + \vec{H_M}$. Thus we should plug in this relationship into the relationship $\vec{M}$  = $\chi_m \vec{H}$ = $\chi_m [\vec{H_0} + \vec{H_M}]$.

However I know this second approch is wrong because, if I solve for the magnetization using Eq.(13.47)

$\vec{M}  = \chi_m [\vec{H_0} -\frac{1}{3}\vec{M}]$.

$\vec{M} = \frac{3+\chi_M}{3\chi_M} \vec{H}_0$

This is incorrect because if I try to plug this into $\vec{B} = \mu_0[\vec{M} + \vec{H}_0]$, I don't recover the relationship $\vec{B} = \mu_0(1+\chi_M)\vec{H}_0$ as I should for simple matter! Can someone please tell me why this second approch is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the Clausius Mossotti relation for electrostatics? I think that you are trying to derive its magnetic counterpart.

Typically, you define $\chi_v$ by the relationship $M=\chi_v H$, the v subscript since the quantity is volumic like $M$ (or more generally in the low field limit the coefficient of the dominating linear term). There is therefore no ambiguity here.

However, if your bulk is made of many individual “atomic” moments each one of atomic susceptibility $\chi$ defined by:
$$
m=\chi H
$$
with $m$ the atomic magnetic dipole moment and $H$ an exterior magnetic field. You then might want to relate this effective $\chi_v$ by the microscopic $\chi$, which I think this is what you were looking for.

However, coming back to your reasoning, the field that an individual atom (which you can assimilate as a uniformly magnetized ball) sees the field created by the other atoms (complement of the ball) and the external field. This is commonly known as shielding. This is different from what you wrote where on the contrary you consider only the field it generates (which should not count) and the external field, therefore forgetting about the other atoms.

The chapter on Ferromagnetism of the Feynman Lectures explains this quite well. Btw, physically, unlike in the electrostatic case where the Clausius Mossotti formula holds reasonably well, this kind of reasoning completely fails for ferromagnetism. You can always artificially fit the geometric factor ($1/3$ for the ball) to match the correct values, but to obtain the correct sign and order of magnitude, you’ll need to incorporate quantum mechanics.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what your saying is, "the field it generates" is not the sheilding field? I guess more fundamentally, what is the H-field in the simple matter relationship M  = χm H ?  Is it the total H-field inside the volume? If so, then how is H = H_M + H_0 not valid? Thanks again!

Comment: The $H$ in the formula is the macroscopic field $H$. Intuitively, this is what you control experimentally. It is typically determined by the free currents using symmetry and Ampere's law, so it should be viewed as the external applied field, to which you want to quantify the response.